# How to undo changes to user preferences in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I was following this tutorial to add GAP (animation) to GIMP, so I can edit multiple layers at once:

https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Installing-GAP-4-9-3-Gimp-GAP-Gimp-2-10

Before adding this, I had an animation option under filters but no option to edit multiple layers.

After adding this, I no longer have an animation option under filters. Does anyone know how to undo this so I have that option again?

I am using GIMP 2.10.12

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Reset.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Plugins`. This should list two folders:

- one in the Gimp installation directory (somewhere under `C:\Program files\...` if you are on Windows)
- one somewhere in your user directory (`C:\Users\{your id}\...`).

If there is a third folder pointing to the GAP installation then remove it.

Otherwise if you navigate to the first one if should contain subdirectories called `animation-play` and `animation-optimize` and these should contain like-named executables. If these directories/executables are not there then you'll have to reinstall Gimp.